# how do are create layout like below in android application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

i want to create android cardview layout like below which has triangle cut at bottom of layout.

[image: sample image from google design]

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: i am thinking to add small triangle at the bottom of the layout. does it seem good idea?

Comment: go ahead, don't think if it is a good idea or not before trying

Answer (score 1):

You can use an image as the background for the bottom of your CardView.

Comment: @Vinay That will work **very well**. Specially, if you use a **tiled** image (one single "triangle" is needed and then it's automatically repeated to fill the width).